# .NET MVC Views being hit, but not rendered to page

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Sitecore 8.0 if that matters (it probably does), but in my stock project I have the main layout being rendered, the layout being hit with a few

```
@{Html.Action();}
```

Method calls in my view. I can see the controller being hit. And if I breakpoint in those nested views I can see those being hit, however when the page is rendered ... nothing! Only the layout is rendered. My dummy test, "This is a test from a partial view" is not rendered even if I put a breakpoint to see what's going  on I can confirm that it is actually being invoked. I'm stumped, any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to render your view.  This will automatically invoke the action:

```
@Html.RenderAction("action");
```

Comment: Derp, duh, went way too deep into this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Html.RenderAction() will render the result directly to the response but will give you better performance.

Html.Action("Action Name", "Controller Name") will return a string with result.

Have you been able to get the text rendered now?  Have you got a placeholder and is it lowercase? Charlie :)